# Why MAKEFLAGS += -j12 is not working anymore with make 4.2

Tags: makefile

I upgraded from `make` 4.1 to 4.2 and my directive at the top of my makefile doesn't work anymore:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -j12
```

I found this on the release note, but it doesn't help:

```
* The amount of parallelism can be determined by querying MAKEFLAGS, even when
  the job server is enabled (previously MAKEFLAGS would always contain only
  "-j", with no number, when job server was enabled).
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't help to solve your issue, but it's a bug:

> bug #49844: 'make -j' without explicit process count sometimes doesn't parallelize

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?48274

Comment: Not the same problem, but definitely the same reason: setting `-j` via `MAKEFLAGS` does not work since 4.2.  I've long rationalized this as a feature, really: there should be only one job server per make session, and that's definitely the case when invoking sub-makes using `$(MAKE)` (which is what the maintainers strongly recommend in any case).  So tweaking the value of `-j` in a sub-make should not have any effect, and in the topmost make it can just be given on the command line (perhaps using a wrapper script)

Comment: This is a strong compatibility break in my opinion. The `MAKEFLAGS` should work for any flags.